# Universal reference in a class template

Tags: c++, c++11, template

I'm writing a templatized container and wanted to use an universal reference for the `Add(T&& object)` function. Check out [isocpp](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) if you need an update on your universal/rvalue references. A quick example from that page states that, since the class is templatized, `T&&` is fully specified and therefore a rvalue, not an universal reference.

```
template <class T, class Allocator = allocator<T> >
class vector {
public:
    ...
    void push_back(T&& x);       // fully specified parameter type ⇒ no type deduction;
    ...                          // && ≡ rvalue reference
};
```

This means that I cannot pass lvalues to the push_back function above.

```
vector<T> list;

list.Add(T()); // rvalue, compiles fine.

T data;
list.Add(data); // lvalue, does not compile.
```

In the case of std::vector this is solved by having a [`push_back(const T& object)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) overload.
However, since the code in my `Add` function is quite complex, I didn't want to copy it over.

However, if I am to templatize my add function, it *does* become universal reference. So I came up with the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Container
{
    public:
    template <class UR = T>
    void Add(UR&& object)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<UR>>, T>::value, "UR and T should be the same!");
        m_Vector.push_back(std::forward<UR>(object));
    }
    std::vector<T> m_Vector;
};

class Data
{
    public:
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main() {
    Container<Data> list;
    Data d;
    list.Add(d);
    return 0;
}
```

I've added the static assert to make sure that people do not actually templatize the `Add` function. Does anyone know a cleaner solution, since this feels a bit of template magic? Should I follow the std method and just copy my add function (which is a bit more complex than this minimal example)? Can anyone come up with a case where my solution will not work?

Here is a [small ideone version](http://ideone.com/6aPLt6) for you to play around with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your solution is principally correct. If you want to play nice with potential generic traits (at the cost of a potentially uglier error message), you'd replace the `static_assert` with [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE):

```
template <
    class UR = T,
    class TypeMustBeT = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::remove_reference_t<UR>, T>::value>
>
void Add(UR&& object)
{
    m_Vector.push_back(std::forward<UR>(object));
}
```

This way, the function `Add` will not exist at all when `UR` is not a forwarding reference for `T`<sup>1</sup>.

If you don't like the "template magic" involved in this and/or the compiler errors generated from misuse, you can solve this by providing the two strongly-typed overloads as `std` does and forward to a common private implementation:

```
void Add(const T& object)
{
  AddImpl(object);
}

void Add(T&& object)
{
  AddImpl(std::move(object));
}

private:
template <class UR>
void AddImpl(UR&& object)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<UR>>, T>::value, "UR and T should be the same!");
    m_Vector.push_back(std::forward<UR>(object));
}
```

This way, you can keep the `static_assert`-using version and keep the static assertion just to check *your* code's correctness, not the *client* code's.

Note that the `static_assert` needs to do `std::remove_cv` after `std::remove_reference`, otherwise it will fail for `UR = const T&`. The same applies to the original code in the question too.

Unrelated to the question at hand, but I assume `using namespace std;` is for this reduced example only and is not present in your real code. It's [very bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1782465) to put that into header files in real code.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that "forwarding reference" is the preferred term instead of "universal reference," since it captures the semantics better.